# npm run serve or bulid fails on linux, but fine on Windows

Tags: vue.js, npm, eslint, vue-cli

Has anyone seen this error that has just started happening on my linux box? `npm run serve` and `npm run build` both run fine on my Windows machine as usual, but, as of yesterday, I get the following error on the linux box.

The code is the same (pulled from the git repo) and `npm install` is run before `npm run serve` or `npm run build`

Any ideas how I can track this down?...

```
root@agilesimulations:/usr/apps/socket-test# npm run serve

> socket-test@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve --port 8098

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                              3:38:16 PM

 error  in ./src/main.js

Syntax Error: Error: Cannot find module '@eslint/eslintrc'


 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8098&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Comment: are `node.js` versions of Windows and Linux the same?

Comment: yes they are the same